Who did the late Pope intend to succeed him in "Conclave"?
In Conclave (2024), the College of Cardinals of the Catholic Church gathers to elect a new pope following the death of the Pope. The film suggests that the late Pope orchestrated certain events, with Cardinal Bellini noting that the Pope was always “eight moves ahead” in chess.
The movie’s plot unfolds with Cardinal Benitez, whom the late Pope secretly made a cardinal, ultimately being elected by the cardinal electors. This suggests that the Pope might have intended for Benitez to succeed him.
However, Benitez was not a popular candidate until the final ballot, likely because his cardinalship had been kept secret, leaving the cardinal electors unaware of him. He only emerged as the leading candidate following a terrorist attack (which the Pope could not have foreseen), which prompted the reactionary conservative Tedesco—an opponent of the Pope’s liberal reforms—to call for a religious war against Islam. Benitez’s response speech against hate resonated, swaying the cardinal electors in his favor.
Given these events, it’s unclear who the late Pope truly intended to succeed him. It seems unlikely to be Tremblay nor Adeyemi, two of the most popular candidates on the early ballots, as the Pope appeared to sabotage their candidacies. Did the Pope favor a fellow liberal, like Bellini or Lawrence? If so, what evidence supports this? Does the book the movie is based on provide further insights?
Who did the late Pope intend to succeed him?

There is no evidence that the Pope favoured any particular person to succeed him.
Rather the novel suggests that the Pope was against certain cardinals and took steps, in some cases, to eliminate them (or was in the process of doing so).
Tremblay had, in fact, already been dismissed from his duties but the Pope died before this could be implemented.
Adeyemi would not have been the Pope's choice, primarily for his views on homosexuality, and, of course, it appears that the Pope took steps to discredit him (at least according to Tremblay, but that is open to discussion) due to an earlier indiscretion.
Tedesco would not have been the Pope's choice due to his extreme anti-Muslim
views.
Bellini seems to have been a likely popular (and in some cases, expected) choice but there is no indication he was favored by the Pope.
Lawrence (Lomeli in the novel) was an unlikely choice to begin with and the Pope did not consider him suitable for the role.

"Some are chosen to be shepherds, and others are needed to manage the farm. Yours is not a pastoral role. You are not a shepherd. You are a manager."
Conclave by Robert Harris

Given the revelations as the end of the story, Benitez was protected by the Pope but there is no specific evidence that he was intended as a successor but it's at least possible.
